# Remove password completely from Macbook Pro Yosemite

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, password

I am setting up a user and don't want a password. When leaving the new password field blank and hitting OK, the message "your new password is empty" and did not let me proceed.

Can anyone please help on macOS ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Sierra (at least that is what I tested) you can remove the password completely:
SystemPreferences->Users&Groups->"ChangePasword":
enter your Old Password, leave the New Password fields open, it will ask you if you really want to leave these open, do not react and hit Enter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dscl . -passwd /Users/foo`.

Don't use `passwd` since a 0 char password isn't valid, and won't accept the input of "nothing"

Answer (score -3):

1. Choose System Preferences from the Apple menu (), then click Users & Groups.
2. Click the lock , then enter account password.
3. Click Login Options.
4. Choose an account from from the “Automatic login” pop-up menu, then enter the password of that account.

Comment: This doesn't remove a password but enables "Automatic" login".